# How to create a view for nested comments in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to have a nested comment system for my project. I have product model so I want to clients can comment on my products. I have my product and comment models and serializers and I related comments to products in product serializer so I can show product comments. what should i do to clients can write their comment for products??? the comments must be nested. this is my code:

#models

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True, related_name='replys')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {self.body[:30]}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

#serializers:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'parent', 'body', 'created']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'name', 'slug', 'image_1',
                  'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5',
                  'description', 'price', 'available', 'created', 'updated', 'comments']
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }
```

#views:

```
class Home(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    search_fields = ['name', 'category__name', 'description']



class RetrieveProductView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, better keep your db normalized, it means that you can't have a field that has many fields (Rule of Normalization 2).
Based on Rest paradigm, you can make comments as another sub-app where it is referenced by its own url (ex localhost:8000/comments)
this will be consumed by the frontend, where the SPA will show for users in one site the product section with the comment section that will be autmotaically reversed to the model of Product at the Backend

Long Story short:
two independent apps communicating together.

N.B: Stocking that way can also help you after for Data Engineering and Data Collection, it optimizes the process of grabbing, stocking and cleaning.